# How to exclude a list of specific category in category widget in new post admin screen?

Tags: hooks

I am trying to exclude a term(id=46) from category widget(default) on new-post screen, but I can not get its id so i can unset or remove it

```
    add_action( 'load-post-new.php', 'add_filter_cat_category' );
    add_action( 'load-post.php', 'add_filter_cat_category' );


function add_filter_cat_category()
    {
        global $typenow;
        if( 'blogs' != $typenow )
            return;
        add_filter( 'the_category', 'filter_cat_category' );
    }

    function filter_cat_category( $cat_name )
    {
        $cat_id = get_cat_ID( $cat_name );
        $category = get_category( $cat_id );
        $count = $category->category_count;
        return "$cat_name($count)";
    }
```

Can anyone help me!

## Finally I found a solution,

it's not projessional job but it's working

```
add_action( 'load-post-new.php', 'add_filter_cat_category' );
add_action( 'load-post.php', 'add_filter_cat_category' );

function add_filter_cat_category()
{
    global $typenow;
    if( 'blogs' != $typenow )
        return;
    add_filter( 'the_category', 'filter_cat_category' );
    add_filter( 'list_terms_exclusions', 'custome_list_terms_exclusions', 10, 2 );
}
// change the name of the exclusions term
function filter_cat_category( $cat_name )
{
    if ( $cat_name == 'old_name' ) {
        $cat_name .= '_extra name'; // this is new name
    }
    return "$cat_name";
}
// hide exclusion ids 
function custome_list_terms_exclusions( $exclusions, $args ) {
    // IDs of terms to be excluded
    $exclude = "46,48";
    $exterms = wp_parse_id_list( $exclude );
    foreach ( $exterms as $exterm ) {
        if ( empty( $exclusions ) )
            $exclusions  = ' AND ( t.term_id <> ' . intval( $exterm ) . ' ';
        else
            $exclusions .= ' AND t.term_id <> ' . intval( $exterm ) . ' ';
    }
    if ( !empty( $exclusions ) )
        $exclusions .= ')';
    return $exclusions;
}
```

Anyelse your ideas is value with me for the future

Answer (score 1):

```
$args = array (  
  'hide_empty' => 1,    
  'exclude' =>array(1,2,3) // id of categories
); 

$categories = get_categories($args);
```

Comment: thank you so much, but I am looking for customizing on new post screen/ dashboard.